# Nativescript - how to change the app start page

Tags: nativescript

In my app, I allow the user to flip between two main pages.

Also, in the `app-root.xml` file, I've got:

`<Frame defaultPage="{{ start-page }}"></Frame>`

In the root model file constructor, I set the start-page name based on the last page navigated to by the user.

To switch between the pages, I use NS page navigation and I clear the navigation history.

It works - but if I navigate the main page a few times and the suspend the app to the background and bring it foreground - all page navigations stop working.

What is the recommended way of changing the main root page?

One way would be to have one big page and toggle the visibility between the two halfs - but I can't do that at this stage - code base is too big.

Comment: did you store the last visited page somewhere ?

Comment: What is `start-page`? Can you share a Playground sample to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: yes the start-page name is stored in NS storage and I set it in the root-model constructor. The app works - it's only when you send it to the background after changing the root page and then to foreground - that all navigations stop working.

Comment: Here's the link to the PG project https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=7UpkGx&v=5.  navigate between the pages a few times and then send to background. startup coupla other apps and then bring the NS app to the foreground - all navigation should have stopped working

Comment: Doesn't happen every time - but most of the time.